# Как и вообще возможно ли сохранить объект класса в файл

Tags: c++, файлы, visual-c++

Как и вообще возможно ли сохранить объект класса в файл целиком
`fin.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(class));` тут как я понимаю работать не будет
[[image]Класс объект которого нужно сохранить](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85p7o.png)

**ниже классы которые используются**

```
class Plane
{
public:
    Plane()=default;
    ~Plane() = default;
    std::string getNumber() const { return number; }
    std::string getBrand()const { return brand; }
    std::string getReleaseDate()const { return releaseDate; }
    double getCarrying()const { return carrying; }
    size_t getPassengersCount()const { return passengersCount; }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Plane&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Plane&);
    void changeItem();
private:
    std::string number;
    std::string brand;
    std::string releaseDate;
    int carrying;
    int passengersCount;
    
};


    class Pilot
{
public:
    Pilot() = default;
    ~Pilot() = default;
    std::string getSurname()const { return surname; }
    size_t getworkExperienceYears() const { return workExperienceYears; }
    std::string getAddress()const { return address; }
    std::string getDateOfBirth()const { return DateOfBirth; }
    double getSalary()const { return salary; }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Pilot&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Pilot&);
     void changeItem();
private:
    std::string surname;
    size_t workExperienceYears;
    std::string address;
    std::string DateOfBirth;
    double salary;
};

class Flight 
{
public:
    Flight() = default;
    ~Flight() = default;
    void setPilotandPlane(Pilot& pi, Plane& pl) { pilot = pi, plane = pl; pilotSurname = pi.getSurname(), planeNumber = pl.getNumber(), planeBrand = pl.getBrand(), cargoWeight = pl.getCarrying(); }
    void changeItem();
    std::string getflightNumber()const { return flightNumber; }
    std::string getFinishDate()const { return finishDate; }
    std::string getStartDate() const { return startDate; }
    std::string getPilotSurname()const { return pilotSurname; }
    std::string getPlaneNumber()const { return planeNumber; }
    std::string getPlaneBrand() const { return planeBrand; }
    double getKm()const { return km; }
    double getCost()const { return cost; }
    std::string getStartPoint()const { return startPoint; }
    std::string getFinishPoint() const { return finishPoint; }
    size_t getCountOfStops() const { return countOfStops; }
    size_t getCountOfSoldTickets() const { return countOfSoldTickets; }
    size_t getCargoWeight() const { return cargoWeight; }
    Pilot& getPilot() { return pilot; };
    Plane& getPlane() { return plane; };
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Flight& flight);
    friend  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Flight& flight);
protected:
    Pilot pilot;
    Plane plane;
    std::string flightNumber;
    std::string finishDate;
    std::string startDate;
    std::string pilotSurname;
    std::string planeNumber;
    std::string planeBrand;
    double km;
    double cost;
    std::string startPoint;
    std::string finishPoint;
    size_t countOfStops;
    size_t countOfSoldTickets;
    size_t cargoWeight;
};
```

Comment: Из самолета и летчика получается рейс, если туда добавить еще один самолет и  другой летчик и несколько  других смесей?..  Будь по вашему, но вы в каждом классе определили операторы потокового ввода и вывода . Вот и введите: fin << obj;

Comment: Короткий ответ: сериализация объекта в JSON Вам в помощь.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сохранить класс в файл, необходимо упаковать содержимое класса так, чтобы при чтении данных можно было восстановить его на любой системе с различными порядками байт. Этот процесс называется [сериализацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), соответственно восстановление класса из упакованных данных называется десериализацией.

В С++ "из коробки" не предусмотрено механизма сериализации, но есть много сторонних библиотек, позволяющих это сделать. Самые известные - это:

1. [Protobuf](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) (разработка Google) [github](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf).
2. Компонента библиотеки boost - [Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: при чем сдесь порядок байт? На него можно вообще забить если нет необходимости поддерживать работу программы на обоих `-endian` машинах, ну или если протокол текстовый - тогда до лампочки какой там порядок байт

Comment: Вы правы, говоря, что "можно забить" если требуется хранить данные в пределах одной системы, но тем самым ограничиваем применение программы. Например была написана программа для Linux x86, тогда при таком подходе можем словить неприятные эффекты на Linux ARM, или Solaris. Про текстовый формат - это тоже хорошо, если не надо хранить большие объёмы, в противном случае бинарные форматы привлекательны своей компактностью.

Comment: еще раз: если нет необходимости поддерживать программу на обоих `-endian` машинах. Улавливаете суть? Если вы пишите какой-нибудь микросервис для работы на стороне сервера - зачем вам париться о порядке байт? Беспокоится о порядке байт нужно только в случае передачи бинарных данных между машинами с разным порядком байт - а это крайне редкий случай, особенно для новичка.

Comment: Я вас понял, уловил суть. Но также я считаю, что мой ответ решает поставленную задачу, а также рассказывает о том, что в основе сериализаци закладывают в том числе принцип переносимости. Если вы считаете, что я не прав и вы можете ответить лучше, опубликуйте свой ответ.

Comment: а я говорил что ответ неверный? Я что-то такого не вижу у себя в комментариях. Я лишь заметил, что напрасно вы приплели порядок байт к сериализации - это очень частный случай, который в подавляющем большинстве случаев не имеет значения

Answer (score 2):

Целиком не получится, потому что `vector` и `string` хранят в себе указатель на память в куче. При записи будут записываться именно указатели, а не данные. Чтобы записать `string` в бинарный файл, необходимо сначала записать количество симолов (т.е. `size()` строки), а потом записать это количество символов. Также и для `vector`. Сначала реализуйте функции для записи классов компонентов, а потом скомпонуйте эти функции внутри функции записи класса агрегатора.

---

Вот код записи обьекта класса `Plane`:

```
size_t str_size = number.size() + 1;
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&str_size), sizeof(size_t));
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(number.c_str()), str_size);

str_size = brand.size() + 1;
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&str_size), sizeof(size_t));
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(brand.c_str()), str_size);

str_size = releaseDate.size() + 1;
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&str_size), sizeof(size_t));
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(releaseDate.c_str()), str_size);

file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&carrying), sizeof(int));
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&passengersCount), sizeof(int));
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ , но я не совсем понимаю про что вы говорите ,fin.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(class)); если про этот метод ,то как я понимаю это не просто перегрузка уголков для вывода в файл ,можно пожалуйста пример